Electromagnetic interaction
Suppose a shape memory alloy coil surrounds a wire carrying current. The coil/spring expands and contracts while current is flowing through the central wire. Does this interaction of the springs expanding and contracting length within the magnetic field create a propelling force in a perpendicular direction? (Lorentz force?)


The law of conservation of momentum is inviolable. Even if some force is created during expansion, it is completely compensated by the force created during contraction.

What if the current through the spring is only cycled when expanding? Does this not, only create a singular force without the compensating force from contraction?
